# Laravel 5.4 symfony new update SetTrustedProxies() needs second parameter

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I'm using a middleware for handle `https` over `Cloudflare`, this is the code:

```
if(env('I_AM_BEHIND_CLOUDFLARE')) 
    $request->setTrustedProxies( [ $request->getClientIp() ] );
if (!$request->secure())
    return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
return $next($request);
```

this code was working before my last `composer update` that updated `symfony` component of `laravel`. it shows an exception about `InvalidArgumentException`.

`symfony` in last update changed `setTrustedProxies()` function that requires second parameter as known headers.

**Question:** How should I set this second parameter?

Answer (score 2):

You should pass as second argument either of `Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL` or `Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR`

Reference: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L575

Comment: +1 because worked with FORWARDED_ALL, but I have a problem with allowing `all` in it, maybe cause security problems and deactivating `Trust` meaning in this function.